# Giving access to a folder to a specific user in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, passwords

I have at my parents' house a Windows 7 machine, with 2 users - "admin" which only I have the password to, and "HomeUser" which doesn't have a password, and which my parents use to log into Windows.

There's one folder, with several files in it, that my mom needs for only her to get access (keep random people away...). I've created a third user "Mom" for her, and put a password that only she and I know (I don't want to give her my admin password). Then on the "secret" folder, I removed "Authenticated Users" and "HomeUser", and added "Mom" with read\write\modify permissions (everything except for Full Control).

What I want to happen is that whenever someone clicks the folder, they will be prompted for her password. However, what actually happens is that when the folder is clicked, the prompt comes up only for the "admin" password (I guess it only looks for users in the Administrators local group). When I add "Mom" to Administrators group (not the best idea but still), I do get prompted for either "admin" or "Mom" password, but when I give the "Mom" password - the folder becomes accessible PERMANENTLY to "HomeUser" (which is the logged-on user).

My desired outcome is that EVERY TIME someone clicks the folder they will be prompted for "Mom"'s password.

Any thoughts?

I'm running a Windows 7 Professional Service Pack 1.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible -- I believe Windows is caching the access rights to the current user, so it won't get prompted again.  I do not know if there is a time limit (I would think it goes away when the current user logs out).

The idea behind this logic is that it would become too cumbersome if the user would need to type in the password every time (they certainly know it, so if they can provide it once, it is assumed they can provide it again) -- the user could always keep the folder open in explorer anyway.

I would suggest that whenever your Mom anticipates needing access to the protected folder, she logs in under user "Mom".  Note that even if the shared user is currently logged in, your Mom can always switch to her account and work from there, then lock the account or log out when not at the computer any more (any time when she would close the folder under the current circumstances).

Answer (score 0):

Go to folder properties in that sharing and you will find their a option to allow the permission for various users..

If you don't find the sahring options then go to your folder options then in that on view and enable the simple view